# Add items to List<object>

Tags: c#

I am new to OOPS.
I want to add items to a list of objects

```
Class ABC
{ int a; int b; int c;}

List<ABC> listabc = new List<ABC>();
```

I am not able to add all three properties of object together as they are being fetched at different times, but I want them to be a part of the same object, for example:
I have different calls to add it to the list

```
listabc.Add(new ABC {a = 10});
listabc.Add(new ABC {b = 20});
listabc.Add(new ABC {c = 30});
listabc.Add(new ABC {a = 40});
listabc.Add(new ABC {b = 50});
listabc.Add(new ABC {c = 60});
```

I want this to be ({10,20,30},{40,50,60}) instead
this will add ({10,0,0},{0,20,0},{0,0,30},{40,0,0},{0,50,0},{0,0,60})
how should I add it to the list?

Comment: `listabc.Add(new ABC {a = 10, b = 20, c = 30});`?

Comment: Whilst @41686d6564 is absolutely correct, your question is incomprehensible to me.  I feel like it's an X/Y problem and you aren't telling us what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Don't bother with a list; you're not using it for anything it was designed to do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add them all at once.

```
listabc.Add(new ABC {a = 10, b=20, c=30});
```

In your example, you are creating a new class each time and populating a different property. You are getting zeros when you do not provide value because the default value for `int` is 0;

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is set up a constructor on your class to pass through the variables:

```
public class ABC
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }

    public ABC (int a, int b, int c) {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
    }
}
```

Then when you populate your class, you can specify the values in your constructor:

```
List<ABC> listabc = new List<ABC>();
listabc.Add(new ABC(10,20,30));
```

Otherwise, when you add an object you need to ensure you specify all parameters.

The way you were adding them, it was the equivalent of only passing through one value, e.g.

```
listabc.Add(new ABC(10,0,0));
listabc.Add(new ABC(0,20,0));
listabc.Add(new ABC(0,0,30));
```

Answer (score 0):

Only

```
listabc.Add(new ABC {10, 20, 30});

Console.Write ($"{listabc[0].a}, {listabc[0].b}, {listabc[0].c}");
```

it's all